# Javascript checkbox checked attribute does not render checked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form on my page that is filled with checkboxes the user can select.

The values are paginated on the server, and because of that whenever the user clicks next or previous, new values are loaded in the form and the previous removed.

I have a variable in my script that holds the selected values.

```
let selectedReaders = new Set();
```

What I am trying to do, is check if a loaded value has been already selected; and if it has, make it checked.

In the code where I add the HTML for each loaded value, I check if it is and set the checked attribute of the checkbox input to false/true.

But when I open the page, all checkboxes are always unchecked.

Here is the code:

```
for(let reader of serverReaders){
        readers.innerHTML += `
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" onclick="addReader(this)"  value="${reader.userID}" id="reader-${reader.userID}" >
            <label class="form-check-label" for="reader-${reader.userID}">${reader.username}</label>
        </div>`
        document.getElementById(`reader-${reader.userID}`).checked = [...selectedReaders].some( id => id === reader.userID)
        console.log(document.getElementById(`reader-${reader.userID}`).checked)
    }
```

For each reader, I first add the label and input a checkbox for them, and then I check the selectedReaders variable if it has an id of the reader(which means it has been selected previously).

If it has been selected previously, I check the checked to true otherwise, it is set to false.

The `console.log` outputs true for the value if it has been selected previously.

This means that the checked attribute is set to true properly, but on the page, checked=true does not render the input checkbox checked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just add a `checked` attribute to the HTML string if it's supposed to be checked, rather than trying to check it manually.

Comment: You can’t use `document.getElementById` for an element that isn’t in the DOM yet. Why not just put `${[ ...selectedReaders ].some((id) => id === reader.userID) ? " checked" : ""}` as an attribute in the template literal above?

Comment: @SebastianSimon, when is an element considered to be in a DOM? Also, the getElementById seems to find the right element, but it's still rendered unchecked. With checked="${[...selectedReaders].some( id => id === reader.userID)}" in the template literal, now every checkbox appears checked except the last one.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, sorry, your solution actually works. I did not copy the part with the question mark.

Comment: @Barracuda See my updated comment; the `checked` attribute was incorrect in the first revision. A [`Node`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node) `node` is in the DOM if `node.isConnected` is `true`; it’s within `document` if `node.ownerDocument` is `document`. A string isn’t a Node and doesn’t contain Nodes.